# Wireshark dumpcap with setcap set to no-root capture failes to start in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark, linux-capabilities

I have recompiled the latest version of Wireshark with prefix /my-path/bin/ and
want to setup non-root capture of packets.
However when I set

`setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /my-path/bin/dumpcap`

then somehow dumpcap cannot be 
started anymore and exits with:

```
/my-path/bin/dumpcap: error while loading shared libraries: libwsutil.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

/my-path/lib/libwsutil.so.0 is present and if I revert the capabilities with

```
setcap -r /my-path/bin/dumpcap
```

I can run dumpcap again. Is there some security feature that I need to take into account? I'm running Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Hi @Konrad - as this is regarding Wireshark setup, you will be better served by asking it on [Wireshark's Forum](https://ask.wireshark.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same issue too today. I "fixed" it by changing the working folder:

```
setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /my-path/bin/dumpcap
cd /my-path/bin
./dumpcap
```